# Vue.js; Inifinite loop with watch on while loop

Tags: vue.js, while-loop, vuejs2, infinite-loop, watch

I have a while loop with an array.  However, this loop becomes infinite because `dealerCards` array is not updated, even it is set in `watch`.  How can I renew the array with `watch` property?

```
<div id="app14">
    <button v-on:click="Stand">Stand</button>
    <p>Dealer: {{dealerCards}}</p>
    <p>Hand: {{dealerHand}}</p>
</div>


<script>
function Draw() {
    return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 13);
}

function CalcHand(cardsArray) {
    cardsArray.forEach(function(c) {
        hand += c;
    });
    return hand;
}


new Vue({
    el: "#app14",
    data: {
        dealerCards: [],
        dealerHand: 0,
    },
    methods: {
        Stand: function() {
            while (this.dealerHand < 17) {
                this.dealerCards.push(Draw());
                console.log("DH: " + this.dealerHand);
            }
        },
    },
    watch: {
        dealerCards: {
            handler: function() {
                this.dealerHand = CalcHand(this.dealerCards);
            },
            deep: true
        },
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: And if you use `computed` instead of `watch` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `watch` never runs.  In general, use computed for synchronous operations and watch for async:

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app14",
    data: {
        dealerCards: [],
    },
    computed: {
        dealerHand() {
            return CalcHand(this.dealerCards);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        Stand: function() {
            while (this.dealerHand < 17) {
                this.dealerCards.push(Draw());
                console.log("DH: " + this.dealerHand);
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Edit: I forgot to mention, fix the `CalcHand` function by initializing `hand`.  Better yet, replace it with a one-line [`reducer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and move it into the computed:

```js
computed: {
    dealerHand() {
        return this.dealerCards.reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0);
    }
},
```

Demo:

```js
function Draw() {
    return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 13);
}

new Vue({
    el: "#app14",
    data: {
        dealerCards: [],
    },
    computed: {
        dealerHand() {
            return this.dealerCards.reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        Stand: function() {
            while (this.dealerHand < 17) {
                this.dealerCards.push(Draw());
                console.log("DH: " + this.dealerHand);
            }
        },
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app14">
    <button v-on:click="Stand">Stand</button>
    <p>Dealer: {{dealerCards}}</p>
    <p>Hand: {{dealerHand}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much. Actually, CalcHand function is more complicated. It is more than calculating sum of the array.